# AngularJs Service Factory not working with IE11

Tags: angularjs

I am writing an AngularJS front end which uses a REST back end. I have a service which uses the Angular $http service to post to the REST back end. I am using a .factory function to register the service. The service works fine using Chrome, but as soon as I tried my app with IE11, an exception is thrown that it cannot find 'myserviceProvider'.  I'm not using a Provider function to create the service I'm using a .factory function. Why cannot IE11 use the .factory function to find/create my service? Anyone with similar experience? I have several other services built with .factory functions and I have no problem; the difference with this service is that is uses the $http service.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem. I had tried to inject my service before the services were created by Angular. Chrome and FireFox let this go IE is more strict and threw an exception. BTW, after I found this, the IE11 console pointed out a syntax error that I had that Chrome and FireFox did not uncover. Lesson learned is that IE11 is more strict and actually can help uncover bugs you didn't know you had.